# How to change inputView of UISearchBar in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, inputview

In iOS6 , I use the below code to change inputView of UISearchbar

```
for (UIView *view in _searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)view;
        [textField setInputView:_myKeyboard];
        break;
    }
}
```

UISearchbar in iOS7 had changed, I don't know how to find textField to change inputView.
Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hierarchy of subview has been changed in iOS7, so you can use the following code:

```
// subviews
NSArray *searchBarSubViews = [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];
for (UIView *view in searchBarSubViews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField* search=(UITextField*)view;
        [search setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:15]];
        search.delegate = self;

        [search setInputView:self.customKeyboard];
        [self.customKeyboard setTextView:search];
    }
}
[self.searchBar reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: You can get the UITextField from the UISearchBar also with this command: [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"]

Answer (score 1):

Use following code :

```
NSArray *subViewsOfSearchBar = [[self.YOurSearchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];
for(int i =0; i< subViewsOfSearchBar.count; i++) {
    if([[subViewsOfSearchBar objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *searchTxtField=(UITextField*)[subViewsOfSearchBar objectAtIndex:i];
        [searchTxtField setInputView:self.customKeyboard];
    }
}
[self.searchBar reloadInputViews];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
for (UIView *view in _searchBar.inputView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)view;
            [textField setInputView:_myKeyboard];
            break;
        }
    }
```

in iOS 7 subview is not working. From iOS7 UI objects have a extra wrapper/container. May be this code will help you.